# How to use JavaScript variable outside if-statement scope between two if-statements when it is declared in one of them?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a nav menu that animates when opening and closing. I use the animating object `TimelineLite` from GSAP. I only need to create it once the menu is open and then I can use it whenever. Once the menu is closed I'll delete the variable because it's useless. I'd like to avoid declaring it outside the click event as a global variable. Is there a better logical way to do this or should I just stick with declaring a global variable?

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {

  if ($(this).is('.top-toggler:not(.active)')) { // If main menu dropdown toggler is inactive
    // Declare the animating object
    var navTimeline = new TimelineLite(new TweenLite($(this).next('.toggleable').children(), 0.75, {margin: '0', transform: 'perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg)', boxShadow: 'inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)'}));
    $(this).addClass('active'); // Give the button class active
    navTimeline.play(); // Open up the menu using the animation
    return;
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { // If it is active
    navTimeline.reverse(); // Reverse the animation to close it
  }

});
```

Comment: Nope, you'll have to define that outside the scope of that click handler. Any variable declared inside will only exist inside that function. You can put it on a global namespace or something, but it has to exist outside the click handler somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to save the object to the element's jQuery data cache. You can then remove/null it whenever you need

```
if ($(this).is('.top-toggler:not(.active)')) {
  var navTimeline = new TimelineLite(...);
  $(this).data("timeline",navTimeline)
  //...
}

if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { 
  var navTimeline = $(this).data("timeline");
  navTimeline.reverse();
  $(this).data("timeline",null);
}
```

Comment: Great, never knew about this. Any consequences to using this method? Can I always use it or do I need to learn somethings about it first?

Comment: No consequences that I know of. You can always use it as along as you have a DOM element to associate the data to. Either by using `$(element).data()` or [`$.data(element,key[,data])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/). Visit the linked documentation pages to learn more about it

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to avoid a global variable you can use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
(function() {
  var navTimeline;

  $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).is('.top-toggler:not(.active)')) { // If main menu dropdown toggler is inactive
      // DO NOT declare here, declared in the IIFE scope
      navTimeline = new TimelineLite(new TweenLite($(this).next('.toggleable').children(), 0.75, {margin: '0', transform: 'perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg)', boxShadow: 'inset 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0)'}));
      $(this).addClass('active'); // Give the button class active
      navTimeline.play(); // Open up the menu using the animation
      return;
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) { // If it is active
      navTimeline.reverse(); // Reverse the animation to close it
    }

  });
})();  // execute the IIFE
```